# How to Figure Out HD path in C Linux

Tags: c, linux

I'm developing a system in C, where i get the SO information, like a memory, swap and etc.

But, i don't know how many hard disks the machine have, and i need to know how can i figure out what are the machine's disks and what are the path of that disk, like /dev/sda or /dev/sdb

How can i do this, but without use `popen()` or `system()`.

I try to use statfs(), but i don't get the expected results.

Someone know how can i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try getting that information from sysfs, e.g.:

```
$ ls -l /sys/block/s{d,r}*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep 25 09:33 /sys/block/sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep 25 09:33 /sys/block/sdb -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep 25 17:06 /sys/block/sr0 -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sr0
```

The above assumes that any block device matching glob `sd*` are hard drives and `sr*` are optical disk drives.

In C on Linux you can use [`glob("/sys/block/s{d,r}*", ...)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) to find these symlinks. Alternatively, open the directory, enumerate its contents and find the symlinks.

Following the symlinks you can find more information about the device.

Comment: But, i don't want open a pipe to get the result of command. Exists another way?